# Is it possible to trigger an event when a form field value in formio form changes?

Tags: angular, formio

I am using formio angular to render a simple form. The form has a birthday field and when initialized, it has a default value and if it is changed, is it possible to emit an event if the default value has been changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```html
<formio
  [form]="formDefinition"
  (change)="onChange($event)"
></formio>
```

You can subscribe for the `change` event which will emit whenever a value in the form is altered.

Comment: It will get triggered all the time if any value in the form field changes. Is there any specific way that i can achieve this only for a specific form field, not for every changes

Comment: You have to do a manual comparison, there's no event for specific fields being changed.